# My PHP code gives error in my log - 1 line

Tags: php

I have a residual API to update item on my webshop. But I'm not quite sure what's going on, but the Rest API keeps calling a 1 line error.

Really hope some can help, because the error is called constantly and our error log just gets bigger and bigger.

**Fail:**
PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach () in /website/...****/***.php

**The line 234 is this:**

```
      foreach( $products_ids  as $pid ) {
update_post_meta ($pid, '_stock', $stockfileArray [$i] -> StockLevel);
update_post_meta ($pid, '_regular_price', $stockfileArray [$i] -> Price);
          update_post_meta ($pid, '_price', $stockfileArray [$i] -> Price);
```

Regards
Christian

Comment: Have you checked what `$ products_ids` is (Not sure about all of the spaces after the `$` signs).

Comment: Why do you put the space between $ and the rest of the variable name?  I've never seen that.

Comment: There is a error in my post.    Because the line is: >>>                                                                                                                                                    foreach( $products_ids  as $pid ){                         So space between ( and $ + again between pid and ) + 2 space between _ids and as               Is it wrong to make these space, it is a developer who made this for me, thats why I'am asking

Comment: Should products_ids be product_ids ?  No 's' on the end of product.  ??  Otherwise, my thought is that $products_ids is not an array.

Comment: @AdamWinter there isn't where it looks like, the post went wrong - sorry.